# UIActivityViewController or UIAlertController cannot be cancelled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I am trying to share a URL using `UIActivityViewController` as shown below. This presents fine, but cannot be cancelled, i.e. tapping the cancel button does nothing. This is only within my app. If I create a test app with a view controller embedded in a navigation controller it works fine. My app has a tab bar controller with navigation controllers and the view controller I am trying to present this from is on the third tab and is the current top view controller.

```
NSString *string =  @"Check this site out";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.apple.com"];

self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL] applicationActivities:nil];          

[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have also tried changing the controller that it is presented from to the tab bar controller and the root view controller of the keyWindow with no luck.

I even tried adding a completion handler as shown below but this does not even get called!

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {

    [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Not sure how to proceed...any suggestions welcome.

**UPDATE:**

Interestingly I have discovered that I cannot cancel/dismiss a UIAlertController either... even with this basic Apple example.

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"  message:@"This is an alert." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that these controllers are always presented from the root view controller. The app I was working with had a root view controller that overrode `dismissViewController:animated:` and didn't call super.